# diagonal and codiagonal morphisms in additive category

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

Consider $R$ a commutative ring and $M$ a $R$-module.

I know that the diagonal homomorphism is defined as follows:

$\Delta_M : M \longrightarrow M \oplus M : m \longrightarrow (m,m)$

I also know that the codiagonal homomorphism is defined as:

$\sigma_M : M \oplus M \longrightarrow M : (m,m') \longrightarrow m+m'$

Now, I want to see which are the diagonal and codiagonal morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ an additive category. I want to justify why the objects and morphisms used in this definition exists. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

The key thing to note is that additive categories have finite biproducts (simultaneous products and coproducts).

In a general abelian category then, taking the pair of maps $\newcommand\id{\mathrm{id}}\id_M,\id_M$ forms a pair of maps from $M$ to the pair of objects $(M,M)$, and hence induces a map $\Delta_M : M\to M\oplus M$, in the case of modules over a ring, you can check that this map obtained from the universal property agrees with the map you gave in your question.

Similarly this same pair of maps is also a pair of maps from the pair of objects $(M,M)$ to $M$, and hence induces a map $\sigma_M:M\oplus M\to M$, and once again you'll see that the universal map agrees with the map that you've given in the case of modules over a ring.